# How to insert values into a column of an empty newly created dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 questions regarding inserting values to a column in dataframe.

I have created an empty dataframe with column names as follows:

```
Titles = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=Titles)
```

And a variable

```
number = 10
```

I would like to fill column C1 with the value of *number* 5 times, so it will result in a dataframe with 5 rows and 3 columns with each row of column C1 has a value of 10.

I tried a lot ways such as with insert:

df.insert(0, 'C1', number)

and with for loops by looping each cell assessed by .iloc.

1. My first question is there a more effective and faster way to insert a column of a dataframe with a fixed value?
2. Let's say there is another dataframe called df2 with 5 rows and 3 columns, I would like to take the second column of df2 and make it as the second column of df, basically take all the values of the rows in the second column of df2 and insert those values to the second column of df. Is there a good to do it?

I have been searching from other resources but still have success. Could somebody please give some light? Thank you.

Comment: If you set the index beforehand, you only need assign a constant to it: `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['C1', 'C2', 'C3'], index=range(5)); df['C1'] = 'abc'`

Answer (score 3):

How about just assign , Notice here I am using list object , which eliminated the index impact

```
number = 10

df.C1=[number]*5
df
Out[85]: 
   C1   C2   C3
0  10  NaN  NaN
1  10  NaN  NaN
2  10  NaN  NaN
3  10  NaN  NaN
4  10  NaN  NaN
```

If assign from another dfs

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'C':[1,2,3,4,5]})

df.C2=df2.C.tolist()
df
Out[90]: 
    C1  C2   C3
0  NaN   1  NaN
1  NaN   2  NaN
2  NaN   3  NaN
3  NaN   4  NaN
4  NaN   5  NaN
```